# Detect click/hover on a shape, not its box-model's rectangle, with Javascript or CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg, event-handling

I'd like to be able to detect *possibly with CSS* clicking / hovering on a shape (`<img>` tag with an SVG source file) but not on the box-model estate around it. In the image below, the area that would listen for a click / hovering is the one in light blue, while the 'extra' estate is in orange.

[image]

In my particular case, I have two circles one on top of the other - the one below listening for a click / hovering. Therefore, I'd like the light blue annulus only to listen for them. However, according to the box model, in order for the underlying circle to detect a click / hovering, the user would have to click or hover on that square orange stripe.

[image]

Comment: Not possible unless you abandon using an `<img>` tag as when SVG is used as an image it basically works as a raster does.

Comment: I see, I didn't think so because with `filter: drop-shadow()` CSS property the browser is aware of the edges of the SVG file. At any rate, how could I insert an SVG image without using an `<img>` tag?

Comment: Open the SVG in a text editor, and grab the code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you would need to convert the image from an SVG and use an image map polygon to specify the area for an onclick event.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/map

Answer (score 0):

You could also achieve this by using two divs (one wraped around the other) with cSS border-radius and background-image set to your image. With [stopPropagation ()](https://wiki.selfhtml.org/wiki/JavaScript/DOM/Event/stopPropagation) and [cancelBubble](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/UIEvent/cancelBubble) you can set the clicking behaviour to your favorite.

**HTML**

```
<div class="big_cycle" onclick="alert ('clicked');">
    <div class="small_cycle" onclick="event.cancelBubble = true; event.stopPropagation ();"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.big_cycle {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #f00;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  border-radius: 25px;
}

.small_cycle {
  width: 28px;
  height: 28px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 10px;
  top: 10px;
  cursor: default;
  background-color: #0f0;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  border-radius: 14px;
}
```

I made a simple Plunker to demonstrate that: [Click me](https://plnkr.co/edit/AYahWzslFePQMMJAowzI)